# grouped regresion in R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to run a multiple linear regression but i am getting the same coefficients for all my grouped variables

```
names<- rep(LETTERS[1:25], each = 20)
daysp<- runif(1:500,1,500)
startdate <-sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 500)
enddate<- sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 500)
class <- rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 125)
amt<- runif(1:500,10000,500000)
2ndclass <- rep(LETTERS[5:8], each = 125)
df<-data.frame(names,daysp,startdate,enddate,class,amt,2ndclass)
```

Changed to factor class and 2ndclass

```
fitted_models = df %>% group_by(names) %>% do(model = lm(daysp ~ startdate + enddate
+ class + 2ndclass + amt, data=df))

fitted_models$models
```

How can i run the regressions and get different coefficients for each group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data = df` explicitly uses the entire data frame `df`, ignoring any grouping. Use `.` to refer to the data that is piped in, which will let `do` use the groups. See the example at the bottom of `?do` for reference:

```
## From ?do
by_cyl <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl)
models <- by_cyl %>% do(mod = lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .))
```

Though, versions of `dplyr` > 1.0 will prefer using `nest_by` (also demonstrated on the `?do` help page):

```
models <- mtcars %>%
  nest_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(mod = list(lm(mpg ~ disp, data = data)))

models %>% summarise(broom::tidy(mod))
```

Comment: I am guessing its the right answer but i am getting errors for both of your answers For the nest_by approach Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `model`.
x contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
i Input `model` is `list(lm(daysp ~ class + amt, data = data))`.
i The error occurred in row 1.  And for the (.) approach Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: That's a data issue within one of your groups. Within (at least) one of your groups, (at least) one of your categorical variables in the model only has one level, and `lm` is complaining because it needs the variables in the model to take at least 2 different levels.

Comment: You could try to drop those groups, or detect them and fit a simpler model for those groups, or simplify the model overall. Or perhaps fit one big model instead of many small ones. Not really sure which will work better for your use case.